# AngularFire - display images from FireStorage in template

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I have Angular web app backed by Firebase database. Each element in database represents an image data. Besides image's metadata, one key in element is FirebaseStorage location of image.

Need to iterage over image elements in template, show metadatas and display images.

Service is taking care of returning realtime database data. Then component class's method takes care of returning image url for FirebaseStorage. Here is [Angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#downloading-files) docs for retrieving image's url.

Need help, with retrieving image's url with dynamic data returned by database elements.

Here is my Component's .ts file:

```js
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  public charts: Observable<any[]>;
  public imgSrc: Observable<string | null>;

  constructor(private DS: DataService, 
    private st: AngularFireStorage) { }

  ngOnInit () {
    this.charts = this.DS.getCharts();
  }

  getImg(imgSrcRaw: string) {
    const ref = this.st.ref(imgSrcRaw);
    this.imgSrc = ref.getDownloadURL();
    return this.imgSrc;
  }
}
```

data.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    charts: Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { 
        this.charts = this.db.list('horizontals_1').valueChanges();
    }

    getCharts() : Observable<any[]> {
        return this.charts;
    }
```

Template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let chart of charts | async">
    <p>{{ chart.symbol }}/{{ chart.comp_symbol }} </p>
    <img [src]="getImg( chart.img_src )" />
</div>
```

PS: Image's URL could be also retrieved directly in Constructor. But I don't know, how to retrieve specific key of one element of Observable array.

Comment: Currently the images are being fetched cleanly?

Comment: Specify where you are stucked in at the moment? Post the data.service.ts file.

Comment: Im on mobile now, cant post my data.service.ts. But I'm sure, data retrieval is working, "charts" observable's items can be accessed.

My question is how to enter src parameter, to retrieve processed source for Firebase access.

Now the images are not being fetched, when inspected, src paremeter is "unknown".

Comment: So what you basically mean that you doesnt know the object key the image src coming from? Is it what you mean?

Comment: Here is the json structure:
{ 
 "horizontals_1": [
 {"symbol": "XTZ",
 "comp_symbol": "BTC",
 "exchange": "binance",
 "img_src": "charts/horizontals/1/0.png"},
 {"symbol": "ETH",
 "comp_symbol": "BTC",
 "exchange": "binance",
 "img_src": "charts/horizontals/1/1.png"},
 {"symbol": "STRAT",
 "comp_symbol": "BTC",
 "exchange": "binance",
 "img_src": "charts/horizontals/1/2.png"}
 ]
}

Comment: I know the image src key, but I need the correct way, how to retrieve it into template, processed.

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this:**

```
<div *ngFor="let chart of charts | async">
    <p>{{ chart.symbol }}/{{ chart.comp_symbol }} </p>
    <img src="{{getImg( chart.img_src )}}" />
</div>
```

**In your component.ts:**

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  public charts: Observable<any[]>;
  public imgSrc: any; // Change imgSrc type

  constructor(private DS: DataService, 
    private st: AngularFireStorage) { }

  ngOnInit () {
    this.charts = this.DS.getCharts();
  }

  getImg(imgSrcRaw: string) {
    let ref = this.st.ref(imgSrcRaw);
    this.imgSrc = ref.getDownloadURL();
    return this.imgSrc;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, when inspecting page, <img> src paremeter is "[object Object]", instead of url

Comment: Can you do a console.log after this `this.imgSrc = ref.getDownloadURL();` line and post me the output here?

Comment: Updated the answer. Chnage the `imgSrc` type to `any` Check now. If it didnt work do a console.log after this this.imgSrc = ref.getDownloadURL(); line and post me the output

Comment: Tried even with changed imgSrc type to any, console output is same:

app.component.ts:38 Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
app.component.ts:38 Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
app.component.ts:38 Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
app.component.ts:38 Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
app.component.ts:38 Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
app.component.ts:38 Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
[object%20Object]:1 GET http://localhost:4200/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This practically means that there isnt any image like this

Comment: Problem could be in way of retrieving image through components class method. Maybe getImg method's code should be incorporated into service, and charts object should return directly processed url.